# Android Activity Life-cycle

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I need to save my filters after closing `Activity`. I'm using `onSaveInstanceState()` to achieve it.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("age", sbAge.getProgress());
    savedInstanceState.putInt("age", spMyStatus.getSelectedItemPosition());
    if(rbMaleMe.isChecked())
        savedInstanceState.putInt("sex", 1);
    else if(rbFemaleMe.isChecked())
        savedInstanceState.putInt("sex", 2);
}
`
```

In `onRestoreInstanceState()` method:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    sbAge.setProgress(savedInstanceState.getInt("age"));
    spMyStatus.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("status"));
    if(savedInstanceState.getInt("sex") == 1)
        rbMaleMe.isChecked();
    else if (savedInstanceState.getInt("sex") == 2)
        rbFemaleMe.isChecked();
}
```

In `onCreate()` method:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
{
    savedInstanceState.getInt("age");
    savedInstanceState.getInt("sex");
    savedInstanceState.getInt("status");
}
```

but it doesn't work.
Just shows empty views when I close and restart the activity.

`onClick()`:

```
switch (v.getId()) { 
    case R.id.btnSaveInfo: 
        onStop(); 
        finish(); 
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onSaveInstanceState()` is called when the OS kills your `Activity` (to reclaim resources for example). It will not be called when you explicitly call `finish()`.

If you would still like to persist your values, you could use [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

(on a side note, do *not* call `onStop()` explicitly)